# Why is (deep) unsupervised and semi-supervised learning so hard?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, optimization, unsupervised-learning, semi-supervised-learning

I recently read a [paper](http://Towards%20Principled%20Unsupervised%20Learning) quoting:

> General unsupervised learning is a long-standing conceptual problem in
>   machine learning. Supervised learning is successful because it can be
>   solved by the minimization of the training error cost function.
>   Unsupervised learning is not as successful, because the unsupervised
>   objective may be unrelated to the supervised task of interest.

I am wondering, is that the only challenge deep unsupervised learning is facing ? 
Shouldn't deep neural network work well with lots of data?

Semi-supervised learning in contrast seems to have a clear objective due to an available training error cost function. Why is it also considered to be hard ? Are the challenges the same as in unsupervised learning or does it have some unique challenges ?

Answer (score 3):

The last sentence of your quotation answers your question. Adding more data won't solve a poorly-defined problem. In the semi-supervised case, adding more unlabeled data won't inherently make the problem easier because you still need a way to score how correct some method is, and in the absence of labels, that's a challenge.